# Clearing references in the collection objects

Tags: memory, collections, hashmap

I have a HashMap which is of Student type. Student is a User defined object, which consists of few property and also one other user defined object called College. Now, after the usage I want to clear all the memory used by HashMap, and in turn all the memory used by Student and College objects as well. So, while nullifying, do I need to explicitly nullify Student and College object and then assign NULL reference to HashMap object? Or only assigning NULL to HashMap object will release the memory used by Student and College object as well?

```
Map<String, Student> myMap = new HashMap<String, Student>
Student std = myMap.get("");
College col = std.getCollege();
col = null; std = null;
myMap = null;
```

Do I need to do all the above in order to free the memory HashMap is using? Or nullifying HashMap will release all the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dig out the answer for this and got to know, when we call clear method on any hashmap object, it internally iterates on all the object/contents in the hashmap and explicitly assign it to NULL. And then set the hashMap's size to 0 in order to clear the hash map. Below is the implementation of clear() method of HashMap class.

```
public void clear() {
    this.modCount += 1;
    Entry[] arrayOfEntry = this.table;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfEntry.length; ++i)
        arrayOfEntry[i] = null;
    this.size = 0;
}
```

You can see this content of HashMap class using jadclipse plugin in your eclipse.